# Phonegap Builld Media Plugin Suspends Music already playing

Tags: cordova, extjs, plugins, build, media

I am building an ios app with phonegap build and sencha touch 2.3.

I am trying to use the media plugin to play a sound when a new message arrives...

But when I am playing some music on my ipad and the app receives a new message the media plugin is playing my new message sound.

But the audio (music) I was playing before that does not start again...

Is this normal behavior or is there some way to get the audio playing again without users interaction ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using HTML and JavaScript, your app will play the sound like a music. That's why you see your "new message sound" as a music playing. You can see the same behavior when you play something on safari.

If something already is playing, the system will pause the music and play your sound, that is interpreted like a music.

So, unfortunately, there's no way to reproduce a sound as a native app would using Phonegap and Sencha Touch.